# SpringRunner dependency Class couldn't be located

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I couldn't find which jar will provide me the dependency of `SpringRunner.class`

I am trying to upgrade my Integration tests to spring-boot 1.4.0

Comment: Did you perhaps declare the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-test` with a version? Otherwise it should automatically use the correct one.

Comment: Yeah I got it resolved now . I added the spring-boot-starter-test dependency but somehow the downloaded spring-test was corrupted and so the dependency was not resolved properly . Thanks for you all your comments .

Answer (score 6):

`SpringRunner.java` is located in the `spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar` file.

In order to use it in a Maven or Gradle project, you should declare a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test`.

Here are the libraries that `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` depends on:

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test: -> 1.4.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:1.4.0.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.4.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:1.4.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:1.4.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.4.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0
|    |    +--- net.minidev:json-smart:2.2.1
|    |    |    \--- net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.1
|    |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.16 -> 1.7.19
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.assertj:assertj-core:2.5.0 -> 2.4.1
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19
|    |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
|    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1 -> 2.2
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.3.0
|    |    \--- org.json:json:20090211 -> 20140107
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.2.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.3.2.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.2.RELEASE
```

[image: SpringRunner.java]

Answer (score 3):

Try manually adding this import:

import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

Answer (score 2):

If someone else reads and has the same problem, I solved the dependency by removing `<scope>test<scope>` from *spring-boot-starter-test*. Indeed, that parameter tells that the dependency is not used at compile time, but only during testing; however, it's not our case.
Here is the new snippet from the pom:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
```

P.S. I additionally matched the version of *spring-boot-starter-test* with *spring-boot-starter-parent*.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for a class in search.maven.org

https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22SpringRunner%22

Answer (score 1):

Use following maven dependencies.

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Spring-test jar and add it manually to the build path by adding external jars. It resolved all the problem for me.

::Download jar from here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/2.5

Answer (score 0):

upgrade spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.0.1.RELEASE

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
```